# Utilization of the Numpy installed on python3.4 in python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I basically use python 3.4 and the numpy 1.3.0 had been installed and launched successfully on my windows machine.
Recently, I've just installed python 2.7, in order to use Brian2 library, but I've an error in traceback as `Importing numpy failed: No module named numpy`, whereas it has been installed and works well under aegis of python 3.4
Actually, when I switch the interpreter address to python 2.7, the problem will be happened, in which the numpy is totally hidden in view of the python 2.7...

Any help?!

Edit:

I even tried to choose python 2.7 (As it was detected automatically in registry), within the re-installation of numpy... but still there is nothing as the installed package in `Python Interpreters -> Python 2.7`

Comment: think you need to install another numpy package for 2.7

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Why?!... Installed numpy 1.3.0 should have known by python 2.7, too... right?!

Comment: i don't know about windows but in linux i need to do two separate installations.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Sorry if I'm confused... Just imagine I get the other numpy package. When I install that, how can I configure that installation merely for the python 2.7?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python x.y (on Windows) generally expects to find 3rd party modules and packages in `.../pythonxy/Lib/site-packages`.  If the module or package is pure python code that is compatible with multiple python versions (such as code that works with 2.6 and 2.7, or 3.3 and 3.4, or much more rarely 2.7 and 3.4), then it is possible to access one copy of the package from multiple site-packages directories.  (This is done with x.pth files, which is another topic not relevant here.)

However, on Windows, anything compiled from C must be compiled for Windows and a particular version of Python, including 32 versus 64 bits.  (This is currently a requirement of Microsoft C, which may change in the future.)  To run with 3.4.x, you installed numpy-1.3.0-for-3.4-winxx.  To run with 2.7, you must install numpy compiled for 2.7.

By the way, current numpy is 1.8, with 1.9 due soon.  You might want to take the opportunity to upgrade.  If you have trouble getting Windows binaries for python extensions, [gohlke's site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) is excellent.

Comment: Nice explanation... So I am going to use unofficial .whl binary files of the library, is which specialized for the target python version...